# How to wrap table rows without duplicating my wrapper div's?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code that will be generated by Wordpress:

```
<h3>
<span class="title">General Settings:</span>
</h3>
<table class="form-table">
<tbody>
<div class="section_box1"><tr class="section1" valign="top">
<th scope="row">Hide Menu Background:</th>
<td>
<input id="" checked="" name="" type="checkbox">
</td>
</tr><tr class="section1" valign="top">
<th scope="row">
Menu Background:
</th>
<td>
<input name="" type="file">
</td>
</tr></div>
<div class="section_box2"><tr class="section2" valign="top">
<th scope="row">Hide Sidebar:</th>
<td>
<input id="" checked="" name="" type="checkbox">
</td>
</tr><tr class="section2" valign="top">
<th scope="row">Hide Site Title:</th>
<td>
<input id="" checked="" name="" type="checkbox">
</td>
</tr></div>
</tbody>
</table>
```

For now there will be two sections (tr.section1 & tr.section2).

Now I  will wrap these sections with two div's (.section_box1 & .section_box2).

So I am using following Jquery:

```
//Lets wrap those two sections inside divs ...
$('tr.section1').not($('tr').eq(1)).each(function(){
$(this).add($(this).nextUntil('.section2')).wrapAll('<div class="section_box1"></div>');
});

    $('tr.section2').not($('tr').eq(3)).each(function(){
    $(this).add($(this).nextUntil('.section3')).wrapAll('<div class="section_box2"></div>');
    });
```

Now the problem with this code is: If I add another setting field (checkbox for example) in my sections my wrapper div's (section_box1 & section_box2) will duplicate (obviously I want to avoid that). 

I have created [**This Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QZKJM/) to show you my problem.

 
So how can I properly wrap my sections without duplicating my wrapper div's and still be able to add more fields inside wrapper div's section_box1 & section_box2? 
I am trying to make this for couple of hours now but no luck:( 

Thank you guys in advance!!

Comment: Thanks for making a nice fiddle. But regarding your question, why are you wrapping `tr`s with `div`s? I don't think that's even valid HTML. What is your goal?

Comment: I want to make accordion like settings... But have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery is ridiculously insanely needlessly complex. :)

If you really just want all the `.section1` `tr`s to be enclosed in one `.section_box1` `div` (and the same for section 2), you can use the following to do the wrapping:

```
//Lets wrap those two sections inside divs ...
$('tr.section1').wrapAll('<div class="section_box1"></div>');
$('tr.section2').wrapAll('<div class="section_box2"></div>');
```

See the update fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QZKJM/1/

Comment: THX man!! Now I can make it valid by wrapping it inside another tr:=) You did really helped me a LOT!!